# Results of foreach loop prints multiple times

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to split a delimited string of postcodes so that instead of it looking like this:

**before:**

row1: ST16,ST17,ST18,ST19,ST20

row2: AT16,AT17,AT18,AT19,AT20

row3: LL16,LL17,LL18,LL19,LL20


**after:**

row1: ST16

row2: ST17

row3: ST18
...etc

each postcode will have its own individual row. I have managed to do this however when i run my code, it seems to be printing the array of postcodes by the number of elements it contains. For example, if there are 11 elements in the array it will print [ST16,ST17,ST18,ST19,...] 11 times. Does anyone know why that is?

```
if ($db_found) {

// Select all fields from bodyshops_master_network table
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM bodyshops_master_network";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

    // Splits the arrays
    $row = explode(",", $db_field['postcodes_covered']);

    foreach ($row as $value) {
        print "<pre>";
        echo implode("<br>", $row);
        print "</pre>";    
    }

}

mysql_close($db_handle);

} else {

print "Database NOT Found ";
mysql_close($db_handle);
}
```

Comment: `echo implode("<br>", $row)` change to `echo $value.'<br>';` You are imploding the entire row in a loop, so you get the entire row, each time the foreach loops. Use the `$value` variable.

Comment: Because your looping $row nth of times but imploding row so if 20 postcodes in explode your get 20 iterations of the implode, remove `echo implode("<br>", $row);` and use `echo $value;` also...

Comment: Obligatory suggestion, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @FDL removing implode() worked perfectly fine for me and stopped the reoccurring prints. Thank you

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I am pretty new to php and stuff so will definitely have a look at that. Thanks!

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have stop using the old mysql functions and switched to mysqli and connect to the database fine but now it doesn't  output any results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreach loop is redundant and should simply be:

```
$text = implode('<br />', $row);
echo "<pre>$text</pre>";
```

If you insist on the loop, then it should be

```
echo '<pre>';
foreach($row as $value) {
    echo $value, '<br />';
}
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

`implode()` does the *exact* opposite of `explode()`.  Basically, it glues the entire array back together with whatever string you want (a `<br>` in this case).  So the only code you would need to display the postcodes in order would be:

```
$row = explode(",", $db_field['postcodes_covered']);
echo implode("<br>", $row);
```

This will output all the postcodes with a line break between them.  The reason you were getting the output 11 times is because there are 11 items in the array, so the `implode()` got called 11 times.